# Is the Rte_IRead API always implemented as a macro?

Tags: autosar

The AUTOSAR_SWS_RTE (R22-11) document gives several examples of `Rte_IRead` and `Rte_IWrite` implementation as macros (see "Example 5.23"). Also, `SWS_Rte_03730` reads:

> Pure API macros, like Rte_IRead and other implicit API functions, do not have a function table entry.

Suggesting that the `Rte_IRead` commands are always implemented as macros.

However, I have an AUTOSAR Authoring tool which declares `Rte_IRead` both as C functions and as macros. In practice, the macro is always selected since the preprocessor comes before the name resolution in C.

Is there an AUTOSAR Authoring tool where the `Rte_IRead` commands are implemented only as functions and not as macros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macros often lead to more efficient code.
However, e.g. when you create a SWC standalone and deliver an object file or library for integration, this would not work any more.
Latest for this, you would need to be able to call a function.

I would expect that all (major) tools support both.